# Downloadable Products - Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup()

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, error, downloadable

The downloadable products are not viewable on the frontend.  When I enable php errors I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a
>   non-object in
>   /chroot/home/taylored/tayloredexpressions.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
>   on line 815

- I've tried disabling all modules, no change.
- I've tried reverting to the default theme, no change.

I don't know if it is a clue or not, but the page cuts off in the middle of this piece of Magento javascript:

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(
```

Anyone have any idea how to debug with this error??? I really could use some help and pointers on how to track this down and fix it.

http://www.tayloredexpressions.com/supplies/downloads/2015-6x6-dated-calendar.html

Magento 1.9.0.1

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue, a third party PayPal rounding fix module for the PayPal rounding issue error 10413 had stashed a file under app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php

That file was still overriding the Magento core even when the module was disabled, making it extra difficult to track down, especially since Magento wasn't spitting out anything helpful debug wise.

Answer (score 1):

You have error with your theme layout XML Block. The catalog.xml block have the problem. Please try to copy catalog.xml from default layout and overwrite it into your custom theme. I hope it would be help. Don't forget to clear your cache.

Comment: I've tried:

Switching to the default theme and clearing caches and reindexing.

Removing the layout folder from the theme and clearing caches and reindexing.

Copying the catalog.xml and downloadables.xml from the base/default/layout into the theme and cleared the cache and reindexing.

I've tried disabling all third party modules and cleared the cache and reindexed, no change.

None of these things had any effect on the issue.

This only affects downloadable type products...such a stumper of an issue.

Any other ideas?  Thanks for the suggestions, any help is appreciated.

Comment: figured it out finally, see my answer.  Thanks for your input it was very much appreciated!