# Configuring Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I filled in the info for **Sales> Google API** and it also said to fill the tracking code in the Head HTML in Design. After doing that I checked the website and everything is loading except when I click on a product or a category. I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on null in
>   /home/bvsecuri/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
>   on line 815

Please help me fix it! I do not know how this happened when yesterday the site was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did this start right when you added the Google Analytics code?

If not, I believe that is just a coincidence.

If you use PayPal on your site, see the following answer which details a PayPal bug that you may be experiencing: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26372/45692.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your catalog.xml file. Copy the catalog.xml file from default or base folder and add it to your current theme folder. Problem will be solved. Dont forget to clear the cache